# Make React Props Readonly in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I heard that React Props is read only by default, however, I could overwrite props value in a component without errors. Is there settings to make props read only?

```
interface Props {
  readonly isText: boolean;
}

const ComponentA: FC<Props> = ({isText}: Props) {
  isText = false // <- I can change isText even if I add readonly. why?

  return <>{isText}</>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript won't detect error when you decompose the object. Try to access it as an object

```
const ComponentA: React.FC<Props> = (prop: Props) => {
  prop.isText = false; // <- error

  return <div>{prop.isText}</div>
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tluwjm?file=App.tsx)

Comment: Do you know the reason why TS won't detect error when the object is decomposed?

Comment: Because when you decompose the props object you're introducing a new _local_ variable called `isText`. You can modify that as much as you like and you're not changing the property on the object, therefore the `readonly` modifier on the type definition is still honoured.